# Magento get CMS pages based on layout

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9.1

So I'm building a custom breadcrumb nav to list all fundraising options. The pages are using a unique layout called `"fundraising_page."` Is there a way to grab the pages only if they have the `"fundraising_page" layout?` So far I have this, which is grabbing every page regardless of the template it is using.

So what I need is only to list the pages that are using the `"fundraising_page"` template.

```
<?php $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());?>
<?php $collection->getSelect()->where('is_active = 1'); ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($collection as $page): ?>
<?php $PageData = $page->getData(); ?>
<?php if($PageData['identifier']!='no-route'){ ?>
<li>
<a href="/<?php echo $PageData['identifier']?>"><?php echo $PageData['title'] ?></a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some well formatted code and using proper methods.

```
<?php
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addFieldToFilter('root_template', 'fundraising_page');
?>
<?php foreach ($collection as $page): ?>
    <?php if ($page->getIdentifier() != 'no-route'): ?>
        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl($page->getIdentifier())?>"><?php echo $page->getTitle() ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks man, worked like a charm! Any way to filter out the current page? So if you're on Fundraising Option 1, Fundraising Option 1 doesn't show in the menu?

Comment: Use `Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier()` - it returns current CMS page identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if($PageData['identifier']!='no-route')` try

```
if($PageData['root_template']=='fundraising_page')
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a go tomorrow.